# PostgreSQL how to add aggregated column to existing query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have project to analyze premier league stats 2011/12 and I wanna operate on one column (scored goals) when playerd from start(1) or substituted(0) and I wanna show name,surname and sum of scored goal when player started game and substituted. which looks like this only for score at home:

[image]

and I wanna make this looks like this

[image]

I know that this subquery is wrong because it summing all goals not by the player.
How to make it looks separate like for van persie 28 scored from start(1) and from bench (0) supposed to be 2?

erd diagram if you wanna see:
https://postimg.org/image/u46b6lve3/

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query counts all the goals because you are not passing player id to it, try changing the query to the following:

```
select player_id as pid, //other columns
select sum(goals) from projekt.statictics where starts = 0 and player_id = pid) as wyjazd
from //conditions
```

You may need to change the column names based on what they are named in the tables.